# Systems of Linear Equations with additional variable

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm preparing for my theoretical computer science exam and stumbled over this Task for solving a Systems of Linear Equations; it countains an additional variable *X* (ℝ)

```
x + y + z = 3    
3x + 5y + z = 9    
2x + 3y + z = x² - 4x +6    
5x + 6y + xz = 15
```

I have to admit that I have no clue of how to solve this problem, as algebra is one my most hated field.

I'd appreciate every advice/solution.

Comment: $y = 3 - x - z \implies 3x + 5(3 - x - z) + z = 9 \dots$

Answer (score 1):

Number the equations (1) to (4) from top to bottom.
$$(2)-(1): 2x+4y=6; x+2y=3\quad(5)$$
$$(3)-(5): x+y+z=x^2-4x+3=3$$
$$x^2-4x=x(x-4)=0$$
If $x=0$:
$$(4): 6y=15; y=\frac52$$
but then $x+2y=5\neq3$, contradiction. $x=4$.
$$(5): y=\frac{3-4}2=-\frac12$$
$$(1): z=3+\frac12-4=-\frac12$$
and you can check that all equations are satisfied when $x=4,y=z=-\frac12$.

Technically (3) and (4) are nonlinear equations, which in general makes analytical solving quite hard. Fortunately we have enough linear relations here to solve the whole problem in a small space.